# Locally installing wordpress. Database problem

Tags: database, localhost

After installing XAMPP on my local machine (Windows 10), I proceeded to unzipping the wordpress files. In the last step I access http://localhost/WP, enter my details and click on install wordpress. After about a 30 seconds wait I get the WSOD (White screen of death, HTTP error 500). In those 30 seconds I noticed many .frm and .ibd files are being created in my database folder. It seems like a timeout issue to me.

I tried changing the timeout out in the php.ini-production and php.ini-development from 30 to 90, but to no avail. I am not too sure if it is working.

I also tried looking for the .htaccess file but could not find it. I understand there is possibly some timeout parameter there too

Any help appreciated

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please [read this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Common_WordPress_Errors) official article from WordPress.

Some from there:

> Before resorting to desperate measures, there are a number of reasons for the WordPress white screen of death:
>
> **1.** A Plugin is causing compatibility issues.
>
>   **2.** Your Theme may be causing the problem.
>
>   **3.** Your Theme directory may be    missing or renamed.